# Oracle C# Call Procedure

Tags: c#

I have such procedure

```
PROCEDURE FILL_NDRMCA (res OUT number)  AS  
begin
   ..........
   res:=1;
end FILL_NDRMCA;
```

when i call procedure from c# i get this exception

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'FILL_NDRMCA'
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored .
```

my c# code

```
SWProcedureExecuter pe = new SWProcedureExecuter("OC_YKB.NDRM.FILL_NDRMCA");
pe.AddParameter("res",String.Empty, SWParameterDirection.Output);
pe.Execute();
Int32  resultResultCode = (Int32)pe.GetValue("res");        
Result =resultResultCode;
```

Can you help me ?
Thanks

Comment: `SWProcedureExecuter`is a custom class, how would we know what happens? Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

in the SP the param is "NUMBER"

But when calling the SP you'r using the value "String.Empty" so the SP recives a VARCHAR param.

Try changing:

```
pe.AddParameter("res", String.Empty, SWParameterDirection.Output);
```

to

```
pe.AddParameter("res", 0, SWParameterDirection.Output);
```

Comment: lem2802 , I changed it but it gaved the same exeption :(

Comment: ok then try pe.Parameters.Add("res", OracleDbType.Int32).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

Comment: now exception is "Value does not fall within the expected range."

Comment: pe.Parameters.Add("res", OracleDbType.Decimal).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

Comment: I tried this ,the same exeption "Value does not fall within the expected range."